# Determine whether iPhone user is on safari screen

Tags: javascript, iphone, safari

Is there a way to determine whether an iPhone user is on actual safari screen or not?

I would like to figure this out using JavaScript, PHP, HTML or JS.

I am building a code that the iPhone user actually see the web page that I relocated.

===============================================================

I must find out whether Safari is running on the background or not.

I know that I can't figure out it unless I run my own application on iPhone.

However, I believe there is a way to figure out it with JavaScript or other language.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I really don't think there is any way to do so, as you can't get access to what iOS is doing.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether [Page Visibility API](http://davidwalsh.name/page-visibility) could help you out.